# \renewcommand inside for cycle won't work

Tags: macros, loops, foreach, pgffor

In the following MWE I'll be providing the command `\asdasd`, and then try to give it the definition "asdasd" through the command `\renewcommand` inside of a for cycle.

I don't know what's going wrong though: this TeX file just won't produce any document at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\DefineAsdAsd}{%
    \providecommand{\asdasd}{}%
    \foreach \cyclesmade in {1,...,2} {%
        \renewcommand{\asdasd}{asdasd}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\DefineAsdAsd
\asdasd

\end{document}
```

How's this possible?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. Pfg protects everything inside a`\foreach` loop inside a group so your renewcommand is local to the for-loop. Use `\gdef` instead of `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @Andrew Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes OK, I have posted my comment as an answer

Answer (score 3):

This is probably a duplicate. [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz)  protects everything inside a `\foreach`-loop inside a group so your `\renewcommand` is local to the for-loop. Use `\gdef` instead of `\renewcommand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\DefineAsdAsd}{%
    \providecommand{\asdasd}{}%
    \foreach \cyclesmade in {1,...,2} {%
        \gdef\asdasd{asdasd}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\DefineAsdAsd
\asdasd

\end{document}
```